# jquery text replace won't work

Tags: jquery

i want to replace the text of the opening button (slidetoggle) when the slider is open:

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
                $('#panel').slideToggle('slow', function() {
                    if ($('#panel').is(':hidden')) {
                        $('#flip').text().replace("close", "open");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#flip').text().replace("open", "close");
                    }
                }); 
            });
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: use this syntax : $('#flip').html("open" or "close")

Comment: `"foobar".replace` isn't a jquery method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work for you:

```
$("#flip").click(function () {
    $('#panel').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        $('#flip').text(function (i, text) {
            if ($('#panel').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#flip').html("close")
            } else {
                $('#flip').html("open")
            }
        })
    }); });
```

And it would be even better if you avoid using the jQuery function so many times. You can use something like this:

> var btnFlip = $("#flip");

And from here on, you can use btnFlip.HTML instead.

Note: As mentioned in the comments, this will replace the text of the button by "close" or "open". So this can be used only if this is the only text of the button.

Comment: html('close') would replace entire content not just the word, example  if text is `button is close` would o/p `open` and not `button is open`

Comment: Oh, that`s correct. I`ve wrongly assumed that this is the only text.

Answer (score 4):

You're replacing the text, but not changing the `text` property to the new value. Try this:

```
if ($('#panel').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#flip').text(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace('open', 'close');
    });
}
else {
    $('#flip').text(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace('close', 'open');
    });
}
```

Comment: Of course, if the *only* content of `#flip` is "open" or "close": `$("#flip").text($('#panel').is(':hidden') ? "open" : "close");`

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the word you are not setting the text back to the element

```
$("#flip").click(function () {
    $('#panel').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        $('#flip').text(function (i, text) {
            if ($('#panel').is(':hidden')) {
                return text.replace("open", "close")
            } else {
                return text.replace("close", "open")
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow 2 important things to speed up process

1) use `$(this)`  whenever you refer to current element

2) Store it in a var when you refer to the same element multiple times

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
      // store in a var since you are referring multiple times
      var flip = $(this);
      $('#panel').slideToggle('slow', function() {
         // get the inner text of the flip 
         var flipText = flip.text();
         // $(this) refers to #panel
         if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {  
         // 'flipText.replace("close", "open")' gives replaced Text
         //  copy back the replaced string 
             flip.text(flipText.replace("close", "open");
         }
         else {
              flip.text(flipText.replace("open", "close");
         }
      }); 
});
```